# Tornado custom error - there is better way?

Tags: python, tornado

In Tornado there is an option to override write_error function of request handler to create your custom error page.

In my application there are many Handlers, and i want to create custom error page when i get code 500.
I thought to implement this by create Mixin class and all my handlers will inherit this mixing.

I would like to ask if there is better option to do it, maybe there is a way to configure application?

Answer (score 7):

My workaround looks kinda similar as you're thinking of. I have a `BaseHandler` and all my handlers inherit this class.

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        """Do your thing"""
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing just like you mention. In order to do it you just have to create a class for each kind of error message and just override the *write_error*, like:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def common_method(self, arg):
        pass


class SpecificErrorMessageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
        if status_code == 404:
            self.response(status_code,
                          'Resource not found. Check the URL.')
        elif status_code == 405:
            self.response(status_code, 
                          'Method not allowed in this resource.')
        else:
            self.response(status_code,
                          'Internal server error on specific module.')


class ResourceHandler(BaseHandler, SpecificErrorMessageHandler):

    def get(self):
        pass
```

The final class will inherit only the specified.